# Open PHP Storm on bash command-line without output

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, bash, phpstorm

Since hours I'm trying to run my phpstorm from commandline, without having any output at all.

**Reason:**

Every day when I come to work, I have multiple tools to start... 2 different vagrant machines, phpstorm etc.

To keep it fast an simple, I decided to create a script doing all this for me...

So after my vagrant's are started, I want to start phpstorm. But no matter what I do, I allways have a prompt in my console.

If I run it like

```
cmd.exe /c /B "/C/Program Files/JetBrains/PhpStorm 2019.2.2/bin/phpstorm64.exe"
```

It calls the exe file but stops for some reason saying: could not open `files/JetBrains...`. This error comes from phpstorm, whats actually wired since it obviously starts it :D

How ever, calling the programm like

```
"/C/Program Files/JetBrains/PhpStorm 2019.2.2/bin/phpstorm64.exe"
```

Opens PHPStorm, but blocks my console... if I hit `CTRL+C` to unlock console, storm is closing.

Running it with a `&` at the end like

```
"/C/Program Files/JetBrains/PhpStorm 2019.2.2/bin/phpstorm64.exe"&
```

Runs the program, locks the console, hitting `CTRL+C` unlocks console, program stays open but still prompting to my console... May im to stupid to google... but I can't find a solution.
Goal is to have a script that starts the tool an keeps the console clean to do some other work.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

**My Setup:**

***cmder.exe** (Console Emulator)*

*Git Installed (So base is **mintty.exe**)*

Comment: Have you thought about adding PHPStorm to the Windows Startup folder?

Comment: of course, but since I want to start it AFTER my vagrant's are up, this is not an option :) And I dont want to have it running all the time... in about 80% its ok, but I do have some "random" days where I dont need it. Sometimes more, sometimes less. So for me is a short command actually this what I need. Thought about to build me an C# programm but a script would be the faster way :)

Comment: Oh, based on your question you said everyday so I figured that was the easiest option.

Comment: sorry for this confusion. Generally its every day but there should still be my decision wether I want to start it or not :D